# Overfull hbox on a tiny equation?

Tags: equations, warnings

My microscopic equation is 2.8 points too wide for some reason, which is quite a lot.  I am reluctant to ignore the warning because if I get more of them I'll start missing important things.

Code is:

```
Applying Snell's law (Equation \eqref{eq:snell}) twice gives us:
\begin{align}
    \theta_2 &= arcsin \left( \frac{n_{vacuum}}{n_{mylar}} sin(\theta_1) \right) \\
    \theta_1 &= arcsin \left( \frac{n_{mylar}}{n_{vacuum}} sin(\theta_0) \right)
\end{align}
which simplifies to
\begin{equation}
    \theta_2 = \theta_0
\end{equation}
We saw earlier that there was a critical angle [blah blah more text...]
```

And the warning is:

```
Overfull \hbox (2.80157pt too wide) (page 6)
```

on line 226, which is the line containing the tiny `\theta_2 = \theta_0`.

I'm probably missing something relatively obvious but I just can't see it.  Any idea ?

Comment: Your code snippet works OK for me (no overfull warning). Can you reduce your actual code to a minimal, compilable version illustrating the problem?

Comment: On an unrelated note, I recommend using `\sin` and `\arcsin`.

Comment: @Niriel It's quite strange and I suspect that it has nothing to do with that equation in particular. However it is necessary to know if you have tried some customization of the equation numbers. Please add the document's preamble.

Comment: Also `vacuum` and `mylar` should be written as `\mathrm{vacuum}` and `\mathrm{mylar}`. It makes a huge difference.

Comment: @Karl: Or `\mathit{...}`.

Answer (score 3):

Local modification of the *mu*-lengths/skips (math-unit skips) could condense the equation enough to avoid the warning yet still produce a consistent enough look to your equation compared to others. [Herbert Voß' mathmode document](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) illustrates the different locations where *mu*-skips are used in an equation:

[image: Muskips in math mode]

The default setting for these *mu*-skips are

```
\thinmuskip=3mu
\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
\thickmuskip=5mu plus 5mu
```

where `1mu=0.05556em`. Perhaps merely adding some shrinkability to `\thinmuskip=3mu minus 3mu` would help.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid warning for the case of small overfull (less than 3pt) write the following

```
\hfuzz = 3pt
```

Comment: Oh, this is very convenient.  I will use this in order to correct the biggest problems first.